# This app is incompatible with Samsung GT-P3110

Tags: android, galaxy

I am using Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3110) for developing my android app.
After I publish app to Google Play Store, it said "This app is incompatible with your Samsung GT-P3110".

Here is my settings:

```
   <supports-screens
       android:largeScreens="true"
       android:normalScreens="true"
       android:smallScreens="true"
       android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

What's wrong with it ? Anyone can help ?

I can download other apps in Google Play Store in my device.

Thanks.

Comment: What else is in your manifest? Like "uses-feature" ?

Comment: I believe that some 7" screens are configured to show up as `xlargeScreens`. Have you tried it with that enabled also?

Comment: Some permissions also implicitly demand phone features. Those have to be made optional then.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is solved. It is because galaxy tab 2 7.0 did not support auto focus for camera. Just remove auto focus feature. It is ok now

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your manifest to remove the autofocus feature:

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />`